# EXTJS 4 grid with pagination not working---issues with store proxy

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

This progress bar pager EXTJS grid works in EXTJS5 but not in EXTJS 4.So,how can i make it work in EXTJS 4.
This is a simple extJS 4 grid with pagination support.I want my EXTJS 4 grid to support pagination.How to make my EXTJS 4 grid with pagination?
My current code is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title>       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jszip.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.define('Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager', {

    requires: ['Ext.ProgressBar'],
    /**
     * @cfg {Number} width
     * <p>The default progress bar width.  Default is 225.</p>
    */
    width   : 200,
    /**
     * @cfg {String} defaultText
    * <p>The text to display while the store is loading.  Default is 'Loading...'</p>
     */
    defaultText    : 'Loading...',
    /**
     * @cfg {Object} defaultAnimCfg
     * <p>A {@link Ext.fx.Anim Ext.fx.Anim} configuration object.</p>
     */
    defaultAnimCfg : {
        duration: 1000,
        /*easing: 'bounceOut' */
    },  

    /**
     * Creates new ProgressBarPager.
     * @param {Object} config Configuration options
     */
    constructor : function(config) {
        if (config) {
            Ext.apply(this, config);
        }
    },
    //public
    init : function (parent) {
        var displayItem;
        if (parent.displayInfo) {
            this.parent = parent;

            displayItem = parent.child("#displayItem");
            if (displayItem) {
                parent.remove(displayItem, true);
            }

            this.progressBar = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar', {
                text    : this.defaultText,
                width   : this.width,
                animate : this.defaultAnimCfg,
                style: {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                },
                listeners: {
                    el: {
                        scope: this,
                        click: this.handleProgressBarClick
                    }
                }
            });

            parent.displayItem = this.progressBar;

            parent.add(parent.displayItem);
            Ext.apply(parent, this.parentOverrides);
        }
    },
    // private
    // This method handles the click for the progress bar
    handleProgressBarClick : function(e){
        var parent = this.parent,
            displayItem = parent.displayItem,
            box = this.progressBar.getBox(),
            xy = e.getXY(),
            position = xy[0]- box.x,
            pages = Math.ceil(parent.store.getTotalCount() / parent.pageSize),
            newPage = Math.max(Math.ceil(position / (displayItem.width / pages)), 1);

        parent.store.loadPage(newPage);
    },

    // private, overriddes
    parentOverrides  : {
        // private
        // This method updates the information via the progress bar.
        updateInfo : function(){
            if(this.displayItem){
                var count = this.store.getCount(),
                    pageData = this.getPageData(),
                    message = count === 0 ?
                    this.emptyMsg :
                    Ext.String.format(
                        this.displayMsg,
                        pageData.fromRecord, pageData.toRecord, this.store.getTotalCount()
                    ),
                    percentage = pageData.pageCount > 0 ? (pageData.currentPage / pageData.pageCount) : 0;

                this.displayItem.updateProgress(percentage, message, this.animate || this.defaultAnimConfig);
            }
        }
    }
});


Ext.onReady(function() {
function JSONToCSVConvertor(counter) 
    {
        var zip = new JSZip();

    for(var i=0; i< Object.keys(counter.levels).length ;i++)
        {
            var CSV = '';
            var row1="Sample v/s Feature"+',';
              for(var p=0;p<Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length;p++)
              {
                row1 += counter.levels[i].samples[p].name + ',';
              }
              row1.slice(0, row1.length - 1);
              CSV += row1 + '\r\n';
              var row2="";
              for(var k=0;k<Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples[0].features).length;k++)
                     {
                       row2 +=counter.levels[i].samples[0].features[k].name + ',';

                        for(var j=0; j< Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length ;j++)
                        {

                        row2 +=counter.levels[i].samples[j].features[k].count+ ',';
                        }
                        row2 +='\n';
                        row2.slice(0, row2.length - 1);
                    }
                     CSV += row2 + '\r\n\n';
                      var fileName = "";
    var title=counter.levels[i].name;
    fileName += title.replace(/ /g,"_");   
     zip.file(title+".csv", CSV);
  /*  var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.href = uri;
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);*/
        }
       /* var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
saveAs(content, "example.zip");*/
content = zip.generate();
    location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + content;


    }



    var familyTable;
    var classTable;
    var orderTable;
    var phylumTable;
    var superkingdomTable;
    var genusTable;
    var panelHeader;

    var counter = {"workflowName":"Workflow-1","levels":[{"name":"family","samples":[{"name":"1660SH_3","features":[{"count":3,"name":"Bacteroidaceae"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteroidaceae"]},{"name":"1660SH_4","features":[{"count":3,"name":"Bacteroidaceae"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteroidaceae"]}]},{"name":"genus","samples":[{
                "name": "1660SH_3",
                "features": [{
                    "count": 8,
                    "name": "Bacteroidia"
                }, {
                    "count": 9,
                    "name": "Bacteroidiaa"
                },
                {
                    "count": 10,
                    "name": "Bacteroidiab"
                },
                {
                    "count": 11,
                    "name": "Bacteroidiac"
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "1660SH_4",
                "features": [{
                    "count": 5,
                    "name": "Bacteroidia"
                }, {
                    "count": 6,
                    "name": "Bacteroidiaa"
                },
                 {
                    "count": 7,
                    "name": "Bacteroidiab"
                },
                {
                    "count": 8,
                    "name": "Bacteroidiac"
                }]
            }]},{"name":"class","samples":[{"name":"1660SH_3","features":[{"count":8,"name":"Bacteroidia"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteroidia"]},{"name":"1660SH_4","features":[{"count":8,"name":"Bacteroidia"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteroidia"]}]},{"name":"order","samples":[{"name":"1660SH_3","features":[{"count":3,"name":"Bacteroidales"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteroidales"]},{"name":"1660SH_4","features":[{"count":3,"name":"Bacteroidales"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteroidales"]}]},{"name":"phylum","samples":[{"name":"1660SH_3","features":[{"count":1,"name":"Deinococcus-Thermus"},{"count":8,"name":"Bacteroidetes"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteroidetes","Deinococcus-Thermus"]},{"name":"1660SH_4","features":[{"count":1,"name":"Deinococcus-Thermus"},{"count":8,"name":"Bacteroidetes"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteroidetes","Deinococcus-Thermus"]}]},{"name":"superkingdom","samples":[{"name":"1660SH_3","features":[{"count":9,"name":"Bacteria"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteria"]},{"name":"1660SH_4","features":[{"count":9,"name":"Bacteria"}],"bacteriaIdList":["Bacteria"]}]}],"projectId":"1455523890090","isBinstat":false,"executionName":"exe-2","projectName":"Project-1"};

for(var i=0; i< Object.keys(counter.levels).length ;i++)
{
     var field=[];   
        var columnList = [];
        var minwidth=0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width;
        var noofitems=Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length;
        var actualwidth=(0.54*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width)/noofitems;
        if(minwidth>actualwidth)
        {
            actualwidth=minwidth;
        }

         columnList.push({
            header: "Sample v/s Feature",
            dataIndex : "Sample v/s Feature",
            width:0.1*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
            columnLines: true,
            locked:true});
        field.push("Sample v/s Feature");
        for(var p=0;p<Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length;p++)
        {

                columnList.push({
                    header: counter.levels[i].samples[p].name,
                    dataIndex : counter.levels[i].samples[p].name, 
                    width:actualwidth,
                    columnLines: true});

                field.push(counter.levels[i].samples[p].name);

        }
        var mydata=[];
         for(var p=0;p<Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples[0].features).length;p++)
        {
            var s=[];
            s["Sample v/s Feature"]='<b>'+counter.levels[i].samples[0].features[p].name+'</b>';
            for(var j=0; j< Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length ;j++)
            {
                s[counter.levels[i].samples[j].name]=counter.levels[i].samples[j].features[p].count;
            }
            mydata.push(s);
        }
        var store =  Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            autoLoad: false,
            pageSize : 2,
            fields: field,
            data: [] ,
            data: {
                    count:mydata.length,
                    data:mydata
                },
                proxy:{
                    type:"memory",
                     enablePaging: true,
                    data:mydata,
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'data',

                    }
                }          
        });
        store.load({
    params: {
        // specify params for the first page load if using paging
        start: 0,          
        limit: 2,

    }
});
var table = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            hidden:true,            
            id : counter.levels[i].name+'_ID',
            store: store,
            columns: columnList,
            columnLines: true,
            width: 0.64*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
            height: 0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
           bbar: {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                pageSize: 2,
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true,
                plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager(),
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: {
                        fn: function(component) {
                            component.down("#refresh").hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

        }); 
 if(counter.levels[i].name=='family')
        { 
            /*var panelHeader='<center>Family</center>';
            Ext.getCmp(counter.levels[i].name+'_ID').setTitle(panelHeader); */
            familyTable   = table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='order')
        { /*var panelHeader='<center>Order</center>';
        Ext.getCmp(counter.levels[i].name+'_ID').setTitle(panelHeader); */
        orderTable=table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='phylum')
        {

            /*var panelHeader='<center>Phylum</center>';
            Ext.getCmp(counter.levels[i].name+'_ID').setTitle(panelHeader);*/
            phylumTable=table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='class')
        {

            /*var panelHeader='<center>Class</center>';
            Ext.getCmp(counter.levels[i].name+'_ID').setTitle(panelHeader); */
            classTable=table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='genus')
        { 
          /*  var panelHeader='<center>Genus</center>';
        Ext.getCmp(counter.levels[i].name+'_ID').setTitle(panelHeader); */
        genusTable=table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='superkingdom')
        {
           /* var panelHeader='<center>Superkingdom</center>';
            Ext.getCmp(counter.levels[i].name+'_ID').setTitle(panelHeader);*/ 
            superkingdomTable=table;
        }
    }
Ext.getCmp('genus_ID').show();
var panel1= {
xtype:'panel',
layout:'vbox',
width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
height: 0.927*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
title:'<center>Levels</center>',
items:[{
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Genus',
    id:'button1',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Genus</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Family',
    id:'button2',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Family</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        }
       ,
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Class',
    id:'button3',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Class</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Order',
    id:'button4',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Order</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Phylum',
    id:'button5',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Phylum</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Superkingdom',
    id:'button6',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>SuperKingdom</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').show();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Export to CSV',
    id:'button7',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
       JSONToCSVConvertor(counter, 'GeMS_Report', true);

    }
        }

        ],
        listeners : {
        afterrender : function(panel) {
            var header = panel.header;
            header.setHeight(0.038*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height);
        }
    }
};
var tablepanel= {
    title:'<center>Genus</center>',
    id:'tablepanel',
    style: 'border: solid Blue 1px',
    xtype:'panel',
    width: 0.64*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    height: 0.538*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    layout:'vbox',
closable:true,
closeAction:'hide',
items:[genusTable,familyTable,classTable,orderTable,phylumTable,superkingdomTable],
listeners : {
        afterrender : function(panel) {
            var header = panel.header;
            header.setHeight(0.038*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height);
        }
    }
};

var sidepanel={
    header:false,
    id:'sidepanel',
    bodyStyle: "background-image:url(http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/120/seamless-geometric-checked-texture-vector-art_120465088.jpg);padding: 120px;",
    width:0.84*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    height: 0.927*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    items:[tablepanel]
}

var cumulative = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    id:'main',
    title: '<center>Cumulative Report</center>',
    layout:'hbox',
    width:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    height: 0.965*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [panel1,sidepanel],
     listeners : {
        afterrender : function(panel) {
            var header = panel.header;
            header.setHeight(0.038*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height);
        }
    }
});
    });

  </script>
  </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code to use paging. important changes: generate data (s) before creating store to add it in code not by method "add". I have added reader to reader count (total count of records used by paging plugin). also addeddockedItems pagingtoolbar to actually use paging toolbar and here is code, it must work

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var field = [];
    var columnList = [];
    var counter = {
        "levels":

            [{
            "name": "class",
            "samples": [{
                "name": "1660SH_3",
                "features": [{
                    "count": 8,
                    "name": "Bacteroidia"
                }, {
                    "count": 9,
                    "name": "Bacteroidiaa"
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "1660SH_4",
                "features": [{
                    "count": 5,
                    "name": "Bacteroidia"
                }, {
                    "count": 6,
                    "name": "Bacteroidiaa"
                }]
            }]
        }, ]
    };
    columnList.push({
        header: "Sample v/s Feature",
        dataIndex: "Sample v/s Feature",
        width: 0.1 * Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
        columnLines: true,
        locked: true
    });
    field.push("Sample v/s Feature");
    for (var p = 0; p < Object.keys(counter.levels[0].samples).length; p++) {

        columnList.push({
            header: counter.levels[0].samples[p].name,
            dataIndex: counter.levels[0].samples[p].name,
            flex: 1,
            columnLines: true
        });
        field.push(counter.levels[0].samples[p].name);
    }

    if (counter.levels[0].name == 'class') {
        for (var p = 0; p < Object.keys(counter.levels[0].samples[0].features).length; p++) {
            var s = {};
            s["Sample v/s Feature"] = '<b>' + counter.levels[0].samples[0].features[p].name + '</b>';
            for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(counter.levels[0].samples).length; j++) {
                s[counter.levels[0].samples[j].name] = counter.levels[0].samples[j].features[p].count;
            }

        }

        var Grid7Store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                fields: field,
                data: {
                    count:s.length,
                    data:s
                },
                proxy:{
                    type:"memory",
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'data',
                        totalProperty: 'count'
                    }
                }
            });


        var classTable = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            style: 'border: solid Blue 1px',
            id: 'family',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store: Grid7Store,

            columns: columnList,
            columnLines: true,
            width: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
            height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    displayInfo: true,
                    store: Grid7Store
                }
            ]

        });

    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your point correctly, pagesize:2 this property should fulfill its function.  can you give example on sencha fiddle or jsfiddle?

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/160l @LightNight  this is the sencha fiddle link.....now pagination is working....but i want to remove the refresh button in the paging toolbar...since it is of no use to me....how to do that?

Comment: where is no any config to just hide refresh button, but you can hide it on afterrerender event. here is fiddle [link to fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1612)

Comment: well, I had that problem too, but could not find solution, cannot help you here. I solved my problem by using server side,  excel generator library to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 0):

as I know your data and store must look like: here is [fillde linki](https://jsfiddle.net/zura101/1h4yjyjg/4/)

```
var myData = [
        count:5,
        data:[
            ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02,  0.03,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42,  1.47,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28,  0.34,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['American International Group, Inc.',  64.13, 0.31,  0.49,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['AT&T Inc.',                           31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Boeing Co.',                          75.43, 0.53,  0.71,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Caterpillar Inc.',                    67.27, 0.92,  1.39,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Citigroup, Inc.',                     49.37, 0.02,  0.04,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company', 40.48, 0.51,  1.28,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Exxon Mobil Corp',                    68.1,  -0.43, -0.64, '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['General Electric Company',            34.14, -0.08, -0.23, '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['General Motors Corporation',          30.27, 1.09,  3.74,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Hewlett-Packard Co.',                 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Honeywell Intl Inc',                  38.77, 0.05,  0.13,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Intel Corporation',                   19.88, 0.31,  1.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['International Business Machines',     81.41, 0.44,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Johnson & Johnson',                   64.72, 0.06,  0.09,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co',              45.73, 0.07,  0.15,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['McDonald\'s Corporation',             36.76, 0.86,  2.40,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Merck & Co., Inc.',                   40.96, 0.41,  1.01,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Microsoft Corporation',               25.84, 0.14,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Pfizer Inc',                          27.96, 0.4,   1.45,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['The Coca-Cola Company',               45.07, 0.26,  0.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['The Home Depot, Inc.',                34.64, 0.35,  1.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['The Procter & Gamble Company',        61.91, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['United Technologies Corporation',     63.26, 0.55,  0.88,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Verizon Communications',              35.57, 0.39,  1.11,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',               45.45, 0.73,  1.63,  '9/1 12:00am']
        ]
];

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    autoLoad: false,
    pageSize : 5,
    buffered: true,
    fields: [
       {name: 'company'},
       {name: 'price',      type: 'float'},
       {name: 'change',     type: 'float'},
       {name: 'pctChange',  type: 'float'},
       {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
    ],
    data: myData,
    proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                enablePaging: true,
                reader: {
                    type: 'array',
                    root: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'count'
                }
            }
});
```

I had same problem you have now. you Have 2 solutions. first one is to reconfigure grid with grid's grid.reconfigure() method or delete old one and create new one with new store, new total property, new data and second one is a little hard to explain taking into consideration my knowledge in English but I will try. first of all you must not parse json manually and you should not add it to store with add method, instead store must be always loaded by its proxy settings. and the important  part. each new page response must have total property more by one than page size  ... ok it's more difficult to explain than I thought. here is example

store proxy configuration:

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.store.myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'MyStore',
    pageSize : 100,
    autoLoad:true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'ajax/?getData',
        reader: {
            type: 'array',
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'count'
        }
    },
    fields: [{
    name: 'company'
    }, {
    name: 'price'
    }, {
    name: 'change'
    }, {
    name: 'pctChange'
    }, {
    name: 'lastChange'
    }]
});
```

server configuration: example is in php

```
<?php
session_name("test");
session_start();

$page = $_REQUEST["page"];
$start = $_REQUEST["start"];
$data = [];
for ($i=0; $i < $start+100; $i++) { 
    $data[]=["ipsa".$i, "ut".$i, "dignissimos".$i, "recusandae".$i, "quae".$i];
}
$_SESSION["start"] =  $start+1;
echo json_encode(["count"=>$start+101,"data"=>$data]);

?>
```

Comment: could you please give a jfiddle for the same?

Comment: what if i add rows to my store dynamically?...then this wouldn't work?........I get data from server side in JSONformat and then i parse that json on extjs ....then using that JSON i add rows to grid store using store.add   .................now how would i get data attribute of store and root attribute of proxy...?

Comment: I will provide example in my last post. you will found solution in it. I have tested example it's working. hope it's that you were looking for

Comment: I have edited my original code,now in my new code i get a JSON from server side(java code)....in my code variable 'counter' stores the JSON i will get,now i use this JSON to add rows to grid store....how to implement pagination now in this code for the grid.....PS: i don't know PHP,i know only java

Comment: I am constrained to parse JSON....so i need to parse JSON.....parsing JSON is compulsory for me........can i do pagination even after using JSON?

Comment: damn, it's exactly what you need.
first of all copy that files to [project_home]/ext/ux/exporter directory.
in your app.js file add requires: [ 'Ext.ux.exporter.Exporter'] and your button which will export must have xtype:'exporterbutton', and it must be in toolbar elemnt, it's all.
here is example [link to fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6st)